# confused about create an IPAD application. change to a UISplitView after logined from UIView using storyboard

Tags: xcode, ipad, authentication, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having an project that required to login, and I am using a Single view application to create the app, so the first page should be a UIView.

After login the page, I decide to change the view to a SplitView which contain a tableview on the left and a view on the right.

when i using storyboard, i create the splitViewController. so, do i need to create a splitViewController .h and .m to handle it?

reason to asking this question is because, when i create a new project using Master-Detail Application and it only contain a MasterViewController .h, .m (tableview) and DetailViewController .h, .m (UIview).

also, may i know how to change the view to a UISplitView when i only got  MasterViewController .h, .m (tableview) and DetailViewController .h, .m (UIview)?